# Is there any chances of having websocket client connecting to an aws ec2 server behind a load balancer?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, websocket

I'm working on a webchat that runs nodejs on port 8080 to publish and 4555 to subscribe using websocket at client side(javascript). When I do this connection direclty to the ec2 instance it works like a charm but in this case I won't have scalability and also have to open port 443 to world. If I make the connection through Load Balancer, chrome/firefox console shows this output and it fails to connect:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://www.domain.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

These are the headers:

```
Request URL: wss://www.domain.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sat, 25 May 2019 13:52:55 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx/1.12.2
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.40
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Upgrade
Cookie: PHPSESSID=nt35ln6ipvbkhflic3obfhd615; AWSALB=l1rePGzfT+/sXpFl0uWliWsb9/Cqdy7V/FjiHF8slLY2pRJ2IbN86SsQJ2UBQZBIfFk8iHKKuCBbe+lLrKcN6toxjiOVVJNxzL2Xaz7BC9aShLzOCTuxkRgmC9/I
Host: www.domain.com
Origin: https:/ /www.domain.com
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key: fN1LLn8igDR5CadSE9UVIw==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Upgrade: websocket
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36
EIO: 3
transport: websocket
```

The javascript client is very simple, for tests purposes:

```
var socket = io('https: //www.domain.com/chat',{'secure':true,transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket']});
```

In nginx config files I have a location /chat proxying the request to :4555 and there is nodejs running and listening.
I have spent 2 days on this and then decided to hire someone who could do that, I had two guys working on it and they couldn't be able to fix.
Can anyone here show me the way?

Comment: Are you using http/s for the load balancer protocol? If you use TCP instead then websockets will work.

Comment: @WarrenG So I need to install classic load balancer? I dont see option for using tcp in this one.

Comment: Are you currently using application load balancer?

Comment: @WarrenG to be honest I'm not sure but its the first option from left to right. And at load balancers list it is tagged as "type: app". I cant check it right now but will see asap

Comment: Have you tried ALB? It has websockets support.

Comment: It's not load balancer, your backend is returning 200 okay instead of 101 Switching Protocols, ALB supports websocket and it just passes the initial http request to backend and your backend needs to ask for upgrade the protocol. Check if backend port from ALB to target it correct.

Comment: @the.malkolm no, I had not. I will try each suggestions given here and let you guys know if it work.

Comment: I know some time has passed but I forgot to update here. None of the suggestions have fixed, so I migrated to a 3rd party channel service.